# Android Emulator Screen Recording Flickering Issue

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, flicker, screen-recording

My emulator device flickers when I record the screen.
I have tried recording in Android Studio with different emulated devices and programs, but all my records flicker heavily.

I know this issue can be solved by doing.
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1hJi.png)

Here someone has answered this but this makes the android emulator performance much slower. Please, someone, tell me to resolve this issue without making the emulator performance slow

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a good fix for this? I'm experiencing this at the moment. Switching the emulated graphics to Software does fix the problem, but then the emulator is annoyingly slow.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried switching emulated performance to hardware?